# Is it possible to set Images in a Viewpager with a if or switch?

Tags: android, if-statement, android-viewpager, switch-statement, android-imageview

I have a `ViewPager` with a `TextView` and an `ImageView`. For the `TextView` I have a `String[]` which contains dynamically added `Strings` and currently just a `int[]` for the `ImageView`.

So my question is, if I can make a `if` or `switch case` to set the a definite image to a text.

Like if the `TextView` is "Text1" the image should be R.drawable.ic_launcher, and if the `TextView` is "Text2" the image should be R.drawable.ic_launcher2 and so on.

---

Here is my code:

```
public class ViewPage extends Fragment {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    Uebung.SessionItemAdapter adapter2;
    String[] Titel;
    int[] Image;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from viewpager_main.xml
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpage, container, false);

        ArrayList<String> strtext=getArguments().getStringArrayList("key");
        String frnames[]=strtext.toArray(new String[strtext.size()]);

        Titel = frnames;

        Image = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};

        viewPager = (ViewPager) layout.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getActivity(), Titel, Image);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);


        return layout;
    }
```

ViewPagerAdapter

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    Context context;
    String[] Titel;
    int[] images;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, String[] Titel, int[] images) {
        this.context = context;

        this. Titel = Titel;
        this.images = images;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Titel.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        TextView txtTitel;

        ImageView image;

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipeview, container,
                false);
        txtTitel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipeviewtitle);

        txtTitel.setText(Titel[position]);

        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swipeViewimage);
        image.setImageResource(images[position]);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Of course you can do anything you want. If you are asking _how_ to do something, then you need to explain more clearly what you're asking for.

Comment: I said it in my last sentence. I want that a specify titel get a specify image . And I think that can be made with a `if` or  `switch` method, but I don't know how. Just about `ImageView image =(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2); if (titel == "text1"){image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select an image resource based on the actual content of the String, you need to either use a series of `if-else` blocks that do String comparisons (with `.equals()`, not with `==`), or you should create a `Map`. If you plan to have a **lot** of these, then I would go with the `Map` as it will perform better than a long chain of `if-else`, but if you only have two or three then you can probably get away with the `if-else`.

With `if-else`:

```
String title = Title[position];
int imageRes = 0;
if ("text1".equals(title)) {
    imageRes = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
} else if ("text2".equals(title)) {
    imageRes = R.drawable.ic_launcher2;
} // etc.
image.setImageResource(imagesRes);
```

With a `Map`:

```
// outside of any method
private static final Map<String, Integer> TITLE_IMAGES = 
    new HashMap<String, Integer>();
static {
    TITLE_IMAGES.put("text1", R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    TITLE_IMAGES.put("text2", R.drawable.ic_launcher2);
}

// in instantiateItem()
String title = Title[position];
Integer imageRes = TITLE_IMAGES.get(title);
if (imageRes == null) { // not found in map
    image.setImageResource(0);
} else {
    image.setImageResource(imagesRes);
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! Now it set the image to the title. But you maybe know why the app close when I go to the third page of the `ViewPager` or when I go to the second page and than to the first page again ? If you need more code I can post it down as an answer.

Comment: You should post a separate question describing exactly the problem you are seeing and post a complete stack trace from logcat from when the crash occurs.